# how to export dynamic column data to excel

Tags: java, spring-mvc, apache-poi

I have to export data to excel **having dynamic number of columns**
using java apache workbook,
on every execution, column details will be saved in ListObject,

which will be dynamically generated and get saved in

```
    List<Object> expColName = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

From the List , I have to obtain individual values and export into every column of the excel sheet,

```
for(int i=0; i<expColName.size(); i++){
         data.put("1",new Object[] {                    
                 expColName.get(i)                  
         });
    }
```

The above code gives only the last column value in the excel sheet

Answer (score 1):

What type is data and how do you read the values from the map?

It seems like you are putting every object into the same "key" of the Map, thats why you only get the last item from the list.

You could try to give it a test with:

```
for(int i=0; i<expColName.size(); i++){
     data.put(i+"",new Object[] {                    
             expColName.get(i)                  
     });
}
```